# PROLOG: Graph path with minimum connections

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I was wondering how I could get the path with the minimum connections, instead of the path with the minimum sum of the connections value. My knowledge is:

```
edge (vertex1, vertex2, value).
```

The predicate should return the path and number of connections.

I have this predicate, but it calculates the path with the minimum value between connections and not the number of connections itself.

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y],L):- 
    edge(X,Y,L).

path(X,Y,[X|W],L):- 
    edge(X,Z,L1), 
    path(Z,Y,W,L2), 
    L is L1 + L2.
shortestPath(X,X,[X,X],0):- !.
shortestPath(X,Y,MinP,MinD):-
    findall([L,P],path(X,Y,P,L),Set),
    sort(Set,Sorted),
    Sorted = [[MinD,MinP]|_].
%
```

Any ideas?

### **EDIT**

I made a couple changes in the code but have no idea why it doesn't work

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y],L):- 
    edge(X,Y,L),
    L is 1.
path(X,Y,[X|W],L):- 
    edge(X,Z,L1), 
    path(Z,Y,W,L2), 
    L is L2 + 1.
shortestPath(X,X,[X,X],0):- !.
shortestPath(X,Y,MinP,MinD):-
    findall([L,P],path(X,Y,P,L),Set),
    sort(Set,Sorted),
    Sorted = [[MinD,MinP]|_].
%
```

my knowledge base is

```
edge(1,2,10).
edge(1,3,1).
edge(3,2,1).
```

I want this shortestPath(1,2,X,Y). to give me the direct path 1 -> 2 but i still get 1 -> 3 -> 2.

Can someonte please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by *minimum connections* you mean *shortest path*, the quick fix would be to fix the sum not to count weight but length. But then, there are better ways for finding the shortest path without `findall/3`.

In any case, you'll easily find plenty of examples for *shortest path*.

Comment: solved my problem
thank you